# Почему приходят неактуальные данные из базы?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
const messagesCollection = database.collection("messages");
let newMessages = await messagesCollection.find({}).toArray();
console.log(newMessages);

await messages.forEach(async (item) => {
await messagesCollection.updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectID(item) },
    { $set: { isImportant: action } }
  );
});

newMessages = await messagesCollection.find({}).toArray();
console.log(newMessages);
```

Оба `console.log` показывают одинаковые результаты, хотя обновление данных проходит корректно(при обновлении страницы происходит такая же выборка, как и в двух примерах выше, данные в ней актуальные). Используется удаленный кластер. Почему так происходит, и как мне получить актуальные данные во второй выборке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, `messages` это массив, поэтому `messages.forEach()` это обычный метод массива, который ничего не возвращает, в том числе не возвращает `Promise` — поэтому даже поставленное перед ним `await` не означает, что исполнение будет ожидать до тех пор, пока все элементы массива будут перебраны. Все вызовы функции, переданной в `messages.forEach()`, будут начаты синхронно и одновременно остановятся, ожидая ответа от `messagesCollection.updateOne()`. И пока все эти ответы ожидаются, вы уже успеваете вызывать `messagesCollection.find()` второй раз и получаете всё ещё старые данные.

Попробуйте заменить `messages.forEach()` на цикл:

```js
for (const item of messages) {
  await messagesCollection.updateOne(
    { _id: ObjectID(item) },
    { $set: { isImportant: action } }
  );
}
```